# Accessing a field on a Django model that is linked to a different model via the User model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Reputation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ....

class Article(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ....
```

I am trying to access the "score" field on the Reputation model from an Article object. I tried the following on an Article object (article_object), but it does not work:

```
article_object.created_by.reputation_set.score
```

Is there any way I can access "score" from an Article object? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `article_object.created_by.reputation.score`? It is one to one field so `reputation_set` does not apply here.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I didn't know that _set did not apply to one-to-one fields, but of course that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `article_object.created_by.reputation.score` instead.

`OneToOneField` auto creates a backward reference with the name of the model in lowercase.

You can override the related object name by setting `related_name` on the field.

Sources

- [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships)
- [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)